# Python. Pandas.Drop column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataFrame object.

```
df = pd.read_csv("new_data.csv", index_col = 0)
```

When I do

```
print df.head()
```

The output was

```
  ... Risk ...
0 ...  2   ...
1 ...  3   ...
...
```

But when I try this
`X = df.drop("Risk", 1).values`

There was an error

> "['Risk'] not found in axis"

Comment: pd.drop() has lots of arguments, try explicitly calling df.drop("Risk", axis=1, inplace=True) and then X = df.values in two separate commands as a troubleshooting approach.

Comment: You could have spaces in your column. maybe try df.columns.str.strip() before the drop

Comment: @MatthewArthur it doesnt work :(

Comment: @ecortazar Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that "Risk" is the name of a column instead of an entry in the first row?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the **position** of your column (among the columns),
you could try to delete your column **by index**.

Assuming that you want to delete column No 3 (count starts from 0,
but does not include any index column), you can write:

```
df.drop(df.columns[3], axis=1)
```

The above code is resistant to any "weird" or additional chars in column names.

Or maybe you should start from `print(df.columns)`? This will show you
what are column names in your DataFrame.